# If $X$ and $Y$ are negatively correlated and $Y,Z$ are negatively correlated, does that mean $X,Z$ are positively correlated?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, correlation

If $Cov(X,Y)<0$ and $Cov(Y,Z)<0$ does that necessarily mean $Cov(X,Z)>0$? Intuitively I'm thinking yes, but I'm trying to prove it.  My thoughts were to look at $E(XZ)$ and condition that on $X$ to see if that helps somehow. I was also thinking that you could consider covariance to be like the angle between two random variables and relate that to cosine somehow but in this case we're not assuming the random variables are centered either.

Comment: Since you mention angles, can you construct three vectors such that each pair are at 120 degrees?

Comment: Oh I see what you're getting at. So once you have the vectors, you could get the corresponding random variables through assigning the coordinates of the vector to a coin flip (In R^2) for example. and then you'd just need two of them to be zero mean

Comment: @Trebor This would give an example 3 random variables that are all negatively correlated. And if you wanted to talk about groups of 4,5, etc random variables, you'd just look in higher dimensions so that you have enough space to ensure the angles are pw > 90

Comment: An explicit construction: $(X, Y, Z) = (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0)$ or $(0, 0, 1)$ with equal probability.  Then $Cov(X, Y) = E(XY) - E(X) E(Y) = 0 - (1/3)^2 = -1/9 < 0$, and similarly $Cov(X, Z) = Cov(Y, Z) = -1/9$.  Geometrically these are three corners of a cube that determine an equilateral triangle.

Comment: Also, one can build [multivariate normal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) with arbitrary covariance matrices, which shows that there are no restrictions of the signs of pairwise covariances for any finite number of random variables.

Comment: @GregMartin - not totally arbitrary covariance matrices, since they have to be positive semi-definite.  So there is a restriction on how negatively correlated the three random variables are, even if it allows them all to be slightly pairwise negatively correlated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X,W$ be independent variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Define
$Y= W-X$ and   $Z=-2W-X$.

Then Cov$(X,Y)=-1$, $\,$  Cov$(X,Z)=-1$ and Cov$(Y,Z)=-1$.